# Git: init, add all and commit with message in one single command

Tags: git

How can I group these 3 commands:

- `git init`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Initialize repository"`

I have this of course, but I'm looking for something shorter & more elegant if that exists:

```
me@local:~$ git init; git add .; git commit -m "Initialize repository"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an alias:

```
git config --global alias.here '!git init . && git add . && git commit --allow-empty -m "Initialize repository"'
```

then use it like

```
git here
```

Note that I added the `--allow-empty` option to `git commit`, which will let this work in an empty directory as well as one with content.